# Error when moving stepper motor - Alexa curtain opener

Tags: esp8266, stepper, home-automation

I've hit a wall with my code and keep getting a Panic error like this:

> Panic /Users/lewisaburrow/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.3.0/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp:98 __yield
>
> ctx: sys 
>   sp: 3ffff9d0 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01b0

Please can you help shed some light on the error?

It's used to open and close curtains using Alexa by tricking it into thinking it is a Belkin WeMo device. It runs on an Adafruit Feather HUZZAH with ESP8266.

When I test the Alexa connection code it works fine. It's based on Fauxmo https://bitbucket.org/xoseperez/fauxmoesp
    And when I try the code in isolation that moves the stepper motor it works just fine.(This is with an Adafruit Featherwing Motor Controller: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2927 ). It's after the two are 'blended' together that I experience this issue...

The entire code looks like this:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#ifdef ESP32
#include <WiFi.h>
#else
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#endif
#include "fauxmoESP.h"
#include "credentials.sample.h"

#define SERIAL_BAUDRATE                 115200
#define LED                             2

fauxmoESP fauxmo;


//--------------------------------------------------
// Motor

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_MS_PWMServoDriver.h"

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 
// Or, create it with a different I2C address (say for stacking)
// Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(0x61); 

// Connect a stepper motor with 200 steps per revolution (1.8 degree)
// to motor port #2 (M3 and M4)
Adafruit_StepperMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getStepper(200, 2);


//-------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------



// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Wifi
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void wifiSetup() {

// Set WIFI module to STA mode
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

// Connect
Serial.printf("[WIFI] Connecting to %s ", WIFI_SSID);
WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);

// Wait
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
}
Serial.println();

// Connected!
Serial.printf("[WIFI] STATION Mode, SSID: %s, IP address: %s\n", WiFi.SSID().c_str(), WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());

}

void setup() {

// Init serial port and clean garbage
Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUDRATE);
Serial.println();
Serial.println();

// Wifi
wifiSetup();

// LED
pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);

// You can enable or disable the library at any moment
// Disabling it will prevent the devices from being discovered and switched
fauxmo.enable(true);

// Add virtual devices
fauxmo.addDevice("bedroom curtain");
//fauxmo.addDevice("switch two"); // You can add more devices
//fauxmo.addDevice("switch three");



// -------------------------------
// Motor

AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz
//AFMS.begin(1000);  // OR with a different frequency, say 1KHz

myMotor->setSpeed(10);  // 10 rpm   


//-------------------------------------------




// fauxmoESP 2.0.0 has changed the callback signature to add the device_id,
// this way it's easier to match devices to action without having to compare strings.
fauxmo.onSetState([](unsigned char device_id, const char * device_name, bool state) {
    Serial.printf("[MAIN] Device #%d (%s) state: %s\n", device_id, device_name, state ? "ON" : "OFF");
    digitalWrite(LED, !state);

    if (state == HIGH) {
      Serial.print("Closing the curtain...");
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("Opening the curtain...");
      openCurtain();
    }

});

// Callback to retrieve current state (for GetBinaryState queries)
fauxmo.onGetState([](unsigned char device_id, const char * device_name) {
    return !digitalRead(LED);
});

}

void openCurtain() {
myMotor->step(100, FORWARD, SINGLE);
}

void closeCurtain() {
myMotor->step(100, BACKWARD, SINGLE);
}



void loop() {

// Since fauxmoESP 2.0 the library uses the "compatibility" mode by
// default, this means that it uses WiFiUdp class instead of AsyncUDP.
// The later requires the Arduino Core for ESP8266 staging version
// whilst the former works fine with current stable 2.3.0 version.
// But, since it's not "async" anymore we have to manually poll for UDP
// packets
fauxmo.handle();

static unsigned long last = millis();
if (millis() - last > 5000) {
    last = millis();
    Serial.printf("[MAIN] Free heap: %d bytes\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());


}

}
```

and this is the full error being reported before the ESP8266 tries to reset itself:

```
[MAIN] Device #0 (bedroom curtain) state: OFF
Opening the curtain...
Panic
/Users/lewisaburrow/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.3.0/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp:98 __yield

ctx: sys  
sp: 3ffff9d0 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01b0  

>>>stack>>>  
3ffffb80:  00000001 00000002 3ffee770 40204b82  
3ffffb90:  4010702c 00007530 00000064 402059fd  
3ffffba0:  00000001 00000064 00007530 40204eca  
3ffffbb0:  00000001 00000000 3ffee984 402053e9  
3ffffbc0:  3ffe84e7 65526574 3ffffba0 3ffffe00  
3ffffbd0:  3ffee78c 00000000 3ffee984 40202204  
3ffffbe0:  3ffee78c 00000000 3ffee984 40202271  
3ffffbf0:  65707954 3ffffc00 00000000 40203881  
3ffffc00:  54534f50 70752f20 632f706e 72746e6f  
3ffffc10:  622f6c6f 63697361 6e657665 48203174  
3ffffc20:  2f505454 0d312e31 736f480a 31203a74  
3ffffc30:  312e3239 312e3836 3933312e 3032353a  
3ffffc40:  0a0d3030 65636341 203a7470 0d2a2f2a  
3ffffc50:  6e6f430a 746e6574 7079742d 74203a65  
3ffffc60:  2f747865 3b6c6d78 61686320 74657372  
3ffffc70:  7475223d 22382d66 4f530a0d 43415041  
3ffffc80:  4e4f4954 7522203a 423a6e72 696b6c65  
3ffffc90:  65733a6e 63697672 61623a65 65636973  
3ffffca0:  746e6576 5323313a 69427465 7972616e  
3ffffcb0:  74617453 0a0d2265 746e6f43 2d746e65  
3ffffcc0:  676e654c 203a6874 0d393932 3c0a0d0a  
3ffffcd0:  6c6d783f 72657620 6e6f6973 2e31223d  
3ffffce0:  65202230 646f636e 3d676e69 66747522  
3ffffcf0:  3f22382d 3a733c3e 65766e45 65706f6c  
3ffffd00:  6c6d7820 733a736e 7468223d 2f3a7074  
3ffffd10:  6863732f 73616d65 6c6d782e 70616f73  
3ffffd20:  67726f2e 616f732f 6e652f70 6f6c6576  
3ffffd30:  222f6570 653a7320 646f636e 53676e69  
3ffffd40:  656c7974 7468223d 2f3a7074 6863732f  
3ffffd50:  73616d65 6c6d782e 70616f73 67726f2e  
3ffffd60:  616f732f 6e652f70 69646f63 222f676e  
3ffffd70:  3a733c3e 79646f42 3a753c3e 42746553  
3ffffd80:  72616e69 61745379 78206574 736e6c6d  
3ffffd90:  223d753a 3a6e7275 6b6c6542 733a6e69  
3ffffda0:  69767265 623a6563 63697361 6e657665  
3ffffdb0:  22313a74 69423c3e 7972616e 74617453  
3ffffdc0:  3c303e65 6e69422f 53797261 65746174  
3ffffdd0:  752f3c3e 7465533a 616e6942 74537972  
3ffffde0:  3e657461 3a732f3c 79646f42 732f3c3e  
3ffffdf0:  766e453a 706f6c65 00003e65 40101ea2  
3ffffe00:  3fff0a5c 00000002 3fff0d0c 4010020c  
3ffffe10:  40102bb5 3ffec9a8 3ffffe60 3fff0d0c  
3ffffe20:  00000000 3ffee78c 3ffeb7c2 40203a5c  
3ffffe30:  54534f50 70752f20 632f706e 72746e6f  
3ffffe40:  622f6c6f 63697361 6e657665 48203174  
3ffffe50:  2f505454 00312e31 3ffe97fc 00000001  
3ffffe60:  000001fa 00007fff 000000ed 4010020c  
3ffffe70:  3ffee960 04c14103 00002200 00000000  
3ffffe80:  3fff0d0c 3fff09bc 00000000 40203a80  
3ffffe90:  3ffe97c0 00000000 3fff0084 40204504  
3ffffea0:  3fff0bdc 00000030 0000000f ffffffff  
3ffffeb0:  3fff026c 3fff0274 00000006 3fff0080  
3ffffec0:  3fff0bdc 3fff0088 3fff0084 4020454f  
3ffffed0:  3fff0bdc 3fff0088 3fff0084 40229c30  
3ffffee0:  000001fa 8b01a8c0 00000018 000001fa  
3ffffef0:  00000018 00000000 3ffeea40 401074e4  
3fffff00:  40100000 00000000 00000064 3fff0270  
3fffff10:  3ffeb79a 3fff0274 3fff09bc 40228139  
3fffff20:  3ffeff94 3fff072c 3fff072c 3ffedaf0  
3fffff30:  00000000 3fff09bc 0000001c 3fff072c  
3fffff40:  3ffeb78c 00000000 3fff09bc 40227535  
3fffff50:  6301a8c0 00000258 00000000 0000001c  
3fffff60:  00000002 0000001a 40207f53 3ffec9a8  
3fffff70:  3ffeb764 3fffdcc0 3ffe9040 3ffe9040  
3fffff80:  40207ec6 3ffec9a8 00000000 3fff079c  
3fffff90:  3fffdc80 00000000 3fff09bc 4021bfbb  
3fffffa0:  40000f49 3fffdab0 3fffdab0 40000f49  
<<<stack<<<

ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,7)


ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7)

wdt reset
```

Comment: `fauxmo.enable(true);` is in different spot in the example at https://bitbucket.org/xoseperez/fauxmoesp

Comment: comment out all the motor code .... do you still get the error?

Comment: Hi @jsotola thanks for your suggestion.
I commented out all the motor code and nothing had a panic this time. I then went back and uncommented the motor code but removed any calls for functions that would involve invoking the code. (Specifically I commented out line 113 where I call for 'openCurtain();' This is also worked without a panic.
So it only seems to panic when the motor code tries to execute something.

Comment: I guess motor code does not finish executing within allowed time slot. Thus watchdog resets the esp.

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem. Is there a way to execute the motor code whilst letting the watchdog know the code is working on something and not to restart?